# What's a good workaround for combining long strings?

Tags: c#

Right now I have it `.Add()` to a `List<string>` but this can get extremely long.

[image]

As you can see here, it added 33554432 strings to the list before finally throwing in the towel.

What can I do better here to workaround this?

### StringBuilder

Since using a `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` it's been better. I haven't encountered the issue since but of course that doesn't mean it CAN'T occur.

### My end goal

A lot of you are asking why I'm trying to combine strings and telling me to just read in chunks and such. This isn't really an option, I'm reading from an IMAP stream and I cannot chunk this as it's to be read to search data and to be shown to the user.

The only way I can reliably chunk it is if I were to create a new `StringBuilder` on-exception and start compiling to that, then maybe once read fully, combine all created StringBuilders into 1 string, that probably wouldn't even work well.

### Im reading the Stream with an Extension ReadLine method

Note this is used for other kinds of operations as well, i know the return bit isn't exactly pretty or optimized for this case either.

```
public static string ReadLine(this Stream stream, ref int bodySize, Encoding encoding, bool returnAsByteString=false) {
    bool bodySizeWasSpecified = bodySize > 0;
    byte b = 0;
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    while (true) {
        #region Try Get 1 Byte from Stream
        try {
            int i = stream.ReadByte();
            if (i == -1) {
                break;//stream ended/closed
            }
            b = (byte)i;
        } catch (IOException) {
            return null;//timeout
        }
        #endregion
        #region If there's a body size specified, decrement back 1
        if (bodySizeWasSpecified) {
            bodySize--;
        }
        #endregion
        #region If Byte is \n or \r
        if (b == 10 || b == 13) {
            #region If ByteArray is Empty and the byte is \n reloop so we dont start with a leading \n
            if (bytes.Count == 0 && b == 10) {
                continue;
            }
            #endregion
            #region We hit a newline, lets finish the reads here.
            break;
            #endregion
        }
        #endregion
        #region Add the read byte to the Byte Array
        bytes.Add(b);
        #endregion
        #region Break if bodysize was greater than 0 but now its 0
        if (bodySizeWasSpecified && bodySize == 0) {
            break;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    if (returnAsByteString) {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, bytes.ToArray().Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
    }
    return encoding.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is that you could use the `StringBuilder` class and use the `Append()` or `AppendLine` function to add the strings to it. This will create a long string with all of them combined.

Comment: How would this help prevent an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: It wouldn't prevent it, but this is usually the convention for combining strings into a single string in a memory efficient manner.

Comment: So far this is working well. Havent encountered the issue since, been about 14 mins now.